# How to dynamically inject a div in the React way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can somebody give me some guidance on how can I dynamically inject a div that could wrap two other rendered divs.

so I have something like this:

```
<div>first div</div> 
<div>second div</div>
```

and after I inject the div would be something like this:

```
<> 
    <div>first div</div> 
    <div>second div</div> 
</>
```

Comment: I want to inject the div after the component is mounted. I don't want to be limited to inject only one div. I would like to inject as many divs as I want.

Comment: Where is `<div>first div</div>` located? It's unclear how components are related. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new state variable called e.g. `shouldShowDiv` and set that to `true` when you want the extra `div` wrapper, and use that in the render method to conditionally add it.

**Example**

```js
const { Fragment } = React;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    shouldShowDiv: false
  };

  toggleShowDiv = () => {
    this.setState(({ shouldShowDiv }) => ({ shouldShowDiv: !shouldShowDiv }));
  };

  render() {
    const { shouldShowDiv } = this.state;
    const content = (
      <Fragment>
        <div>first div</div>
        <div>second div</div>
      </Fragment>
    );

    return (
      <Fragment>
        {shouldShowDiv ? (
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}>{content}</div>
        ) : (
          content
        )}
        <button onClick={this.toggleShowDiv}> toggle wrapper </button>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: How about `let Wrapper = showDiv ? p => <div {...p} /> : Fragment` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a HoC to wrap any other component, showing the component as-is or div-wrapped based on a prop

```
const wrap = Component => ({wrapped, ...props}) => {
  const content = <Component {...props} />;
  if (wrapped) return <div>{content}</div>;
  return content;
}

const TwoDivs = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div>first div</div>
    <div>second div</div>
  </React.Fragment>
);

const WrappedTwoDivs = wrap(TwoDivs);

const App = () => <WrappedTwoDivs wrapped={true} />
```